# Is it possible to play sound in Firefox for Android

Tags: android, firefox

Can't find such details on Firefox for Android, is it possible to play or make any audio alert with for ex. HTML5 on 2.x android device?

Comment: I'd try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Audio

Comment: Tried in Opera Mobile 12 and it works )

Comment: Note that on my FF 53 Android, the content of the `audio` tag is not played even when `autoplay="autoplay"`. The user has to click the play button, and the player (seems to actually be an embeded VLC) will play the sound, while making the page non-interactive. So `Notification API` might be a better idea in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the audio HTML element, you can also use the Web Audio APIs. See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Audio_API